# How can I use passed in int's to declare the size of an array within c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my code, the user is asked to input the number of columns and rows within a Maze. From here I would like to use these input's to define the Size of an array. However these are not constants and therefore they're not accepted.

```
maze[rows][columns] //ERROR: EXPRESSION MUST HAVE A CONSTANT A
```

Currently Maze is hardcoded as:

```
maze[4][5]
```

I was wondering if there was a work around for this problem or if someone would be able to look at my Code and explain to me how I could create a new Array using these values whilst storing the values from the old array, I believe this needs pointers. I've included my code below:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
//Maze Size
#define SIZE 5
using namespace std;

bool isSafe(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int x, int y);
bool isValid(int x, int y);
void findShortestPath(char maze[4][5], int visited [4][5], int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist, string& p_route,string route);
void userInput();
void createMaze(int rows, int columns, string filename);



int main()
{
    userInput();
}

bool isSafe(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int x, int y)
{
    if (maze[x][y] == 'x' || visited[x][y] || maze[x][y] == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool isValid(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 4 && y < 5 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

void findShortestPath(char maze[4][5], int visited[4][5], int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist,string&p_route,string route)  //I&J Start Point, X&Y End point
{
    bool solved = false;
    // if destination is found, update min_dist
    while (!solved)
    {


        if (i == x && j == y)
        {
            p_route = route;
            min_dist = min(dist, min_dist);
                if (min_dist != INT_MAX)
                {
                 cout << "The shortest path from source to destination has length " << min_dist << endl;
                 cout << "The route through the maze is: " << p_route << endl;

                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Destination can't be reached from given source";
                }
            solved = true;
            return;
        }

        // set (i, j) cell as visited
        visited[i][j] = 1;

        // go to bottom cell
        if (isValid(i + 1, j) && isSafe(maze, visited, i + 1, j))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i + 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("S"));

        // go to right cell
        if (isValid(i, j + 1) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j + 1))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j + 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("E"));

        // go to top cell
        if (isValid(i - 1, j) && isSafe(maze, visited, i - 1, j))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i - 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("N"));

        // go to left cell
        if (isValid(i, j - 1) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j - 1))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j - 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("W"));

        // Backtrack - Remove (i, j) from visited mazerix
        visited[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

void userInput()
{
    string filename;
    int rows;
    int columns;
    cout << "Please input the name of your maze!" << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please input the amount of rows in your maze!" << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please input the amount of columns in your maze!" << endl;
    cin >> columns;
    cout << endl;
    createMaze(rows, columns, filename);


}

void createMaze(int rows, int columns, string filename)
{
    int startRow = 0;
    int startColumn = 0;
    int endRow = 0;
    int endColumn = 0;
    int column = 0;
    char maze[4][5];
    ifstream input(filename);
    char data = input.get();
    string route;
    string p_route;

    while (!input.eof())
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            while (data != '\n' && !input.eof())
            {
                if (data == 'A')
                {
                    startRow = row;
                    startColumn = column;
                }
                if (data == 'B')
                {
                    endRow = row;
                    endColumn = column;
                }
                maze[row][column] = data;
                column++;
                data = input.get();
            }
            column = 0;

            data = input.get();
        }
    }
    input.close();
    cout << "The Maze being solved is: " << endl;
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            cout << maze[y][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    input.close();
    // construct a mazerix to keep track of visited cells
    int visited[4][5];

    // initially all cells are unvisited
    memset(visited, 0, sizeof visited);

    int min_dist = INT_MAX;
    findShortestPath(maze, visited, startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn, min_dist, 0, p_route, route);
}
```

Comment: Use a vector of vectors if you need the size to vary at runtime :)

Comment: I've been told this a couple of times now, my only worry is I dont really understand them even after reading up on them. Would I have to change most of my other methods for the vector to function properly?

Comment: Vectors support access through `operator[]` just like arrays, plus a few additional things. You will be able to change method signatures to not take in the container size, because vectors have a `.size()` that says how many elements are in them. But if a `maze` is a vector of vectors instead of an array of arrays, something like `maze[x][y]` will still get the `y + 1`th element of the `x + 1`th row.

Comment: So instead of `char maze[4][5]` I could use `vector<vector<char>>maze` ? If that's the case what do I do with the size?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you could either make the sizes global constants (`const int rows = 4; const int cols = 5;` and `char maze[rows][cols]` or you could make the functions templates: `template <int rows, int cols> bool isSafe(char maze[rows][cols], int visited[rows][cols], int x, int y)`.